# half circle links on edges/sides of page

Tags: html, css

I have the following code which makes 2 links in circles on the right and left of the page.

```css
[class*="navigation"] .nav-previous,
[class*="navigation"] .nav-next {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
[class*="navigation"] .nav-previous {
  left: 0px;
}
[class*="navigation"] .nav-next {
  right: 0px;
}
[class*="navigation"] .nav-previous a,
[class*="navigation"] .nav-next a {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 35px 40px;
  color: #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
}
[class*="navigation"] .nav-previous a {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
  transform-origin: right 50%;
  right: 2px;
}
[class*="navigation"] .nav-next a {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg) translateX(-50%) translateY(50%);
  transform-origin: left 50%;
  left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-previous">
  <a>...</a>
</div>

<div class="nav-next">
  <a>...</a>
</div>
```

I only want to show half circles with the link centered inside

Comment: you should remove the `[class*="navigation"]` from your snippet, the elements don't have any classes that contain 'navigation'

Comment: The html is a snippet from larger code which has navigation class

Comment: then add the navigation class to the elements? your css isn't currently doing anything in the snippet when you run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

Make a circle and then use `position` to place it half way down the div and half to the left/right

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  height: 100vh;
}
.container {
  background: #666;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.slider_nav {
  background: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.prev {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 50px;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  left: -50px;
}
.next {
  padding: 20px 50px 20px 20px;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  right: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider_nav prev"><span> < </span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider_nav next"><span> > </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to center of those circles to be on the edges of the pages. If so, you'll have to adjust for 50% of the width of you circles.

With '...' as your link, you can see in chrome that you have a total computed width of 101px.

[image: computed size]

Knowing that, you can just change your CSS like so...

`.nav-previous { left: -50px; }
.nav-next { right: 50px;}`